# Why is my ALTER TABLE statement to ADD a PRIMARY KEY not working?

Tags: mysql, database

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stock_number | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year         | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| make         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| color        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price        | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trim         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE trucks ADD PRIMARY KEY(stock_number);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: @Ahmed     you want stock_number is primary key?

Comment: @MohitKumar yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key has to be unique. The error message indicates that you have multiple rows with an empty `stock_number` column. You need to fill all those in with different values before you can make this column the primary key.

Comment: Ohhhhh! ok that makes more sense now. Ok, thank you. @barmar